# Why a Sierpinski space is not obtainable from a pseudometric?

Tags: general-topology

Why a Sierpinski space is not obtainable from a pseudometric?

---

can somebody please give me the answer

Answer (score 4):

A [pseudometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space) is a symmetric function: if $\rho$ is a pseudometric on a set $X$, then $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$ for all $x,y\in X$. This means that if $\tau$ is the topology on $X$ generated by $\rho$, and $x,y\in X$, then

$$x\in\operatorname{cl}_\tau\{y\}\text{ if and only if }y\in\operatorname{cl}_\tau\{x\}\;.$$ This is not the case with the [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), however: in that we have $0\in\operatorname{cl}_\tau\{1\}$, not $1\notin\operatorname{cl}_\tau\{0\}$. Thus, the Sierpiński topology on $\{0,1\}$ cannot be generated by a pseudometric.